# Boost Property Tree fails to retrieve simple JSON in multi-threaded context

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-propertytree

I am trying to parse a simple JSON string using [Boost.PropertyTree](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) in my C/C++ application.

```
{"header":{"version":42,"source":1,"destination":2},"coffee":"colombian"}
```

Here is how I've set it up in my C/C++ multi-threaded application (manually defining the JSON string to demonstrate the issue).

ParseJson.cpp

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

#include "ParseJson.hpp"

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using boost::property_tree::read_json;
using boost::property_tree::write_json;

extern "C" MyStruct * const parseJsonMessage(char * jsonMessage, unsigned int const messageLength) {
    MyStruct * myStruct = new MyStruct();
    // Create empty property tree object.
    ptree tree;

    if (myStruct != nullptr) {
        try {
            // Create an istringstream from the JSON message.
            std::string jsonMessageString("{\"header\":{\"version\":42,\"source\":1,\"destination\":2},\"coffee\":\"colombian\"}");   // doesn't work
            std::istringstream isStreamJson(jsonMessageString);

            // Parse the JSON into the property tree.
            std::cout << "Reading JSON ..." << jsonMessageString << "...";
            read_json(isStreamJson, tree);
            std::cout << " Done!" << std::endl;

            // Get the values from the property tree.
            printf("version: %d\n", tree.get<int>("header.version"));
            printf("source: %d\n", tree.get<int>("header.source"));
            printf("coffee: %s\n", tree.get<std::string>("coffee").c_str());
        }
        catch (boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path badPathException) {
            std::cout << "Exception caught for bad path: " << badPathException.what() << std::endl;
            return nullptr;
        }
        catch (boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_data badDataException) {
            std::cout << "Exception caught for bad data: " << badDataException.what() << std::endl;
            return nullptr;
        }
        catch (std::exception exception) {
            std::cout << "Exception caught when parsing message into Boost.Property tree: " << exception.what() << std::endl;
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
    return myStruct;
}
```

The `read_json()` call appears to complete but the `get()` calls to retrieve the parsed data from the property tree fail:

```
Reading JSON ...{"header":{"version":42,"source":1,"destination":2},"coffee":"colombian"}... Done!
Exception caught for bad path: No such node (header.version)
```

I am using Boost 1.53 on RHEL 7 (compiler is gcc/g++ version 4.8.5), and I've tried both suggestions mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8156948/3987854) related to Boost.PropertyTree and multi-threading. I've defined the [`BOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22089792/3987854) compile definition globally for the project. I also tried the atomic swap solution suggested for that post. Neither of these had any effect on the symptoms.

Oddly enough, I can use the other [public methods](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html) for Boost.Property tree to grab the values manually:

```
std::cout << "front.key: " << tree.front().first << std::endl;
std::cout << "front.front.key: " << tree.front().second.front().first << std::endl;
std::cout << "front.front.value: " << tree.front().second.front().second.get_value_optional<std::string>() << std::endl;
```

which shows the JSON was actually parsed:

```
front.key: header
front.front.key: version
front.front.value:  42
```

Note, I had to use `std::string` to grab the `header.version` value, as trying to use `get_value_optional<int>()` crashes also.

However, this manual approach is not scalable; my application needs to accept several, more complicated JSON structures.

When I tried more complicated JSON strings, these were also successfully parsed, but accessing values using the [`get()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#idp61934976-bb) methods similarly failed, this time crashing the program. Here is one of the GDB backtraces I pulled from the crashes, but I wasn't familiar enough with Boost to get anything useful from this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffebfff700 (LWP 7176)]
0x00007ffff5aa8200 in std::locale::locale(std::locale const&) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install boost-system-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64 boost-thread-1.53.0-28.el7.x86_64 bzip2-libs-1.0.6-13.el7.x86_64 elfutils-libelf-0.176-5.el7.x86_64 elfutils-libs-0.176-5.el7.x86_64 glibc-2.17-292.el7.x86_64 keyutils-libs-1.5.8-3.el7.x86_64 krb5-libs-1.15.1-37.el7_7.2.x86_64 libattr-2.4.46-13.el7.x86_64 libcap-2.22-10.el7.x86_64 libcom_err-1.42.9-16.el7.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64 libselinux-2.5-14.1.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64 openssl-libs-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64 pcre-8.32-17.el7.x86_64 systemd-libs-219-67.el7_7.2.x86_64 xz-libs-5.2.2-1.el7.x86_64 zlib-1.2.7-18.el7.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff5aa8200 in std::locale::locale(std::locale const&) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff5ab6051 in std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::imbue(std::locale const&) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x000000000041e322 in boost::property_tree::stream_translator<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, int>::get_value(std::string const&) ()
#3  0x000000000041c5b2 in boost::optional<int> boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >::get_value_optional<int, boost::property_tree::stream_translator<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, int> >(boost::property_tree::stream_translator<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, int>) const ()
#4  0x000000000041aa61 in boost::enable_if<boost::property_tree::detail::is_translator<boost::property_tree::stream_translator<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, int> >, int>::type boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >::get_value<int, boost::property_tree::stream_translator<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, int> >(boost::property_tree::stream_translator<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, int>) const ()
#5  0x000000000041985d in int boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >::get_value<int>() const ()
#6  0x0000000000418673 in int boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> >::get<int>(boost::property_tree::string_path<std::string, boost::property_tree::id_translator<std::string> > const&) const ()
#7  0x0000000000414f4a in parseJsonMessage ()
#8  0x000000000040d8cd in ProcessThread () at ../../src/Processing.c:906
#9  0x00007ffff7bc6ea5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x00007ffff55538cd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

FWIW, I tried putting this code into a simple (single-threaded) main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using boost::property_tree::read_json;
using boost::property_tree::write_json;

int main(int numArgs, char * const * const args) {
    
    ptree tree;

    try {
        // Create an istringstream from the JSON message.
        std::string jsonMessageString("{\"header\":{\"version\":42,\"source\":1,\"destination\":2},\"coffee\":\"colombian\"}");
        std::istringstream isStreamJson(jsonMessageString);

        // Parse the JSON into the property tree.
        std::cout << "Reading JSON..." << jsonMessageString << "...";
        read_json(isStreamJson, tree);
        std::cout << " Done!" << std::endl;
        // Print what we parsed.
        std::cout << "version: " << tree.get<int>("header.version") << std::endl;
        std::cout << "source: " << tree.get<int>("header.source") << std::endl;
        std::cout << "coffee: " << tree.get<std::string>("coffee") << std::endl;
    }
    catch (boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path badPathException) {
        std::cout << "Exception caught for bad path: " << badPathException.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    catch (boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_data badDataException) {
        std::cout << "Exception caught for bad data: " << badDataException.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    catch (std::exception exception) {
        std::cout << "Exception caught when parsing message into Boost.Property tree: " << exception.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "Program completed!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code works just fine:

```
bash-4.2$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.exe
bash-4.2$ ./main.exe 
Reading JSON...{"header":{"version":42,"source":1,"destination":2},"coffee":"colombian"}... Done!
version: 42
source: 1
coffee: colombian
Program completed!
```

So, **why won't the Boost.PropertyTree `get()` methods work for a multi-threaded application?** Could the fact that the multi-threaded application is a mix of C and C++ code be causing an issue? I see that my specific compiler version (GCC 4.8.5) hasn't been [explicitly verified](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/property_tree/appendices.html#property_tree.appendices.compatibility) with this Boost library... Could this be a compiler issue? Or is the Boost 1.53 version buggy?

---

*An update based on provided answer:*

Admittedly, my original code for the `parseJsonMessage` method was messy (a product of dozens of debugging iterations and ripping out code that wasn't relevant to the problem). A more condensed version that is free of distractions (and possible red herrings) is the following:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

#include "DirectIpRev3.hpp"

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using boost::property_tree::read_json;
using boost::property_tree::write_json;

extern "C" void parseJsonMessage2() {
    // Create empty property tree object.
    ptree tree;
    std::string jsonMessageString("{\"header\":{\"version\":42,\"source\":1,\"destination\":2},\"coffee\":\"colombian\"}");   //doesn't work
    std::istringstream isStreamJson(jsonMessageString);
    try {
        read_json(isStreamJson, tree);
        std::cout << tree.get<int>("header.version") << std::endl;
        std::cout << tree.get<int>("header.source") << std::endl;
        std::cout << tree.get<std::string>("coffee") << std::endl;
    }
    catch (boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path const & badPathException) {
        std::cerr << "Exception caught for bad path: " << badPathException.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_data const & badDataException) {
        std::cerr << "Exception caught for bad data: " << badDataException.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception const & exception) {
        std::cerr << "Exception caught when parsing message into Boost.Property tree: " << exception.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Running this condensed function in my multi-threaded program yields an exception:

```
Exception caught when parsing message into Boost.Property tree: <unspecified file>(1): expected object or array
```

Without the exception handling, it prints a bit more info:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_parser_error> >'
  what():  <unspecified file>(1): expected object or array
```

I'm still not too sure what might be causing the failure here, but leaning towards using [nlohmann](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) as suggested.

Comment: Good updates. I would +1 again if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, don't use Property Tree to "parse" "JSON". See [nlohmann](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) or [Boost.JSON](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/index.html)

Further

- you're using raw `new` and `delete` apparently without good reason
- You have unused parameters
- you're catching polymorphic exceptions by value
- you're leaking memory on any exception and returning null pointers when there are allocation errors

Combining these, I'm 99% certain that your crashes are caused by something else: [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) has a tendency to show up elsewhere after memory corruption (e.g. stack thrashing or use-after-delete, out-of-bounds etc.).

### Using My Crystal Ball

1. A guess: you didn't show, but the struct probably looks like

   ```
   typedef struct MyStructT {
       int version;
       int source;
       char const* coffee;
   } MyStruct;
   ```

   A naive mistake would be to assign `coffee` the same way you print it:

   ```
   myStruct->coffee = tree.get<std::string>("coffee").c_str();
   ```

   The "obvious"(?) problem here is that `c_str()` points to memory owned by the value node, and transitively by the `ptree`. When the function returns that pointer is stale. OOPS. [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)
2. You are allocating the struct with `new` (even though it is likely POD because of the `extern "C"`, so it gives you a false sense of security, since all the members have indeterminate values anyways).

   Another naive mistake would be to pass that C code that de-allocates with `::free` (like it does with everything `malloc`-ed, right). That's another potential source of UB.
3. If you had "nailed" the first idea e.g. with `strdup` you might run into problems with more leaked memory. Even if you use `delete myStruct` correctly (or start using `malloc` instead), you will have to remember to `::free` the string allocated with `strdup`.
4. Your API is typical C-style (which is probably on purpose) but leaves the door wide open to passing the wrong `messageLength` causing out-of-bounds read.  The chance of this happening is raised due to the observation that you're not even using the arguments in your own example code above.

### MULTI-THREADED STRESS TEST

Here's a multi-threaded stress test live on Coliru. It does 1000 iterations on 25 threads.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f94e56342d63840e)**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

typedef struct MyStructT {
    int version;
    int source;
    char* coffee;
} MyStruct;

//#include "ParseJson.hpp"

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using boost::property_tree::read_json;
using boost::property_tree::write_json;

extern "C" MyStruct* parseJsonMessage(char const* jsonMessage, unsigned int const messageLength) {
    auto myStruct = std::make_unique<MyStruct>(); // make it exception safe
    // Create empty property tree object.
    ptree tree;

    if (myStruct != nullptr) {
        try {
            // Create an istringstream from the JSON message.
            std::istringstream isStreamJson(std::string(jsonMessage, messageLength));

            // Parse the JSON into the property tree.
            //std::cout << "Reading JSON ..." << isStreamJson.str() << "...";
            read_json(isStreamJson, tree);
            //std::cout << " Done!" << std::endl;

            // Get the values from the property tree.
            myStruct->version = tree.get<int>("header.version");
            myStruct->source = tree.get<int>("header.source");
            myStruct->coffee = ::strdup(tree.get<std::string>("coffee").c_str());
            return myStruct.release();
        }
        catch (boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path const& badPathException) {
            std::cerr << "Exception caught for bad path: " << badPathException.what() << std::endl;
        }
        catch (boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_data const& badDataException) {
            std::cerr << "Exception caught for bad data: " << badDataException.what() << std::endl;
        }
        catch (std::exception const& exception) {
            std::cerr << "Exception caught when parsing message into Boost.Property tree: " << exception.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <list>

int main() {
    static std::string_view msg = R"({"header":{"version":42,"source":1,"destination":2},"coffee":"colombian"})";

    auto task = [] {
        for (auto i = 1000; --i;) {
            auto s = parseJsonMessage(msg.data(), msg.size());

            ::printf("version: %d\n", s->version);
            ::printf("source: %d\n", s->source);
            ::printf("coffee: %s\n", s->coffee);

            ::free(s->coffee);
            delete s; // not ::free!
        }
    };

    std::list<std::thread> pool;

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
        pool.emplace_back(task);

    for (auto& t : pool)
        t.join();
}
```

The output (sorted and uniq-ed):

```
  24975 coffee: colombian
  24975 source: 1
  24975 version: 42
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response! I apologize, as my initial `parseJsonMessage` function was not as minimal as possible, and left a lot to be assumed. You raised several good points, which certainly may have been contributing to the odd behavior. I posted a more condensed version above, which I believe addressed/removed the trouble spots you identified, but is still having issues. It is certainly encouraging to see that your example works so well though!

Comment: I'm still a bit suspicious this may be an issue with the compiler/Boost versions I'm using. I tried your example on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f94e56342d63840e) but couldn't find a way to adjust the compiler/Boost versions, so I tried [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/) instead. This example ran great using the latest defaults on Wandbox, but it didn't run when I adjusted the compiler and Boost versions to match mine (4.8.5 and 1.53 respectively). As you advised, I'll probably switch to nlohmann's JSON solution, but my curiosity is still piqued.

Comment: 1.53 is old. Like: [February 4th, 2013 old](https://www.boost.org/users/history/). I answered a similar question [9 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156948/is-boostproperty-treeptree-thread-safe/8157464#8157464). I also think I remember some parsers being completely rewritten in a certain boost release, most likely after 1.53.

Comment: Indeed, 1.59 introduced [A new JSON parser with full Unicode support.](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_59_0.html) . Wandbox confirms a problem [with 1.58](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PcE7wuYbxEZMYoow), success [with 1.59](https://wandbox.org/permlink/waGejUzc3rZbgsUJ)

Comment: Note that [PropertyTree is still ***not a JSON library***](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+%22not+a+json+library%22)

Comment: Much appreciated, these links are super helpful! I noticed there hadn't been much activity with Boost [PropertyTree](https://github.com/boostorg/property_tree/graphs/code-frequency) in quite some time, which raised by suspicions. It looks like upgrading Boost to get [Boost.JSON](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/index.html) might be the best solution for my project.